# Continuous background grid in virtualizing canvas?

Tags: wpf, user-interface, wpf-4.0, ui-virtualization

In my WPF application I have ItemsControl which has [ZoomableCanvas](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaelr/archive/2010/08/11/zoomableapplication2-a-million-items.aspx) as Panel which provides the Virtualization mechanism for the Canvas. **This is working perfectly.** This Canvas needs to have a Graph like background. When I use the xaml below, the **grid is generated but only to the extent of the Viewport** (at load time). So when scrolled you see the background grid getting clipped vertically and horizontally. In the performant-virtualized-wpf-canvas this was handled by adding child Visuals to the canvas as Backdrop.

```
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <ZoomableCanvas x:Name="ZCanvas" Loaded="ZoomableCanvas_Loaded" >
                        <ZoomableCanvas.Background>
                            <DrawingBrush TileMode="Tile" Stretch="Fill"  
                                          Viewport="0 0 100 60" ViewportUnits="Absolute" 
                                          ViewboxUnits="Absolute" >
                                <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                                    <GeometryDrawing Geometry="M0,0 L0,1 0.03,1 0.03,0.03 1,0.03 1,0 Z" Brush="Gray" />
                                </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                            </DrawingBrush>
                        </ZoomableCanvas.Background>
                    </ZoomableCanvas>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```

To elaborate on the problem:  Please see these images:

[image]

On Load --- the background grid is visible and the Left of the child is quite far off from 0,0

On Scrolling Right and back -- the background grid is clipped and the child appears to start from leftmost point in Canvas

How can we have a Grid background which stretches the entire width of ZoomableCanvas ? And How do we fix the On Scroll issue?

Any help / hints sincerely appreciated.